# How to prevent 301 response redirection from being cached, without disabling default redirection?

Tags: ios, caching, redirect

I am implementing a REST client for a server I do not control. The server returns HTTP 301 with "Cache-Control: no-cache". NSURLConnection is caching the response in spite of the "Cache-Control" header. How do I prevent caching without reimplementing the whole HTTP redirection logic myself?

I use simple NSURLConnection with NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy for the NSURLRequest.

The NSURLConnection delegate method connection:willCacheResponse: is called for the final response after the redirection of 301, but not for the 301 response itself, which is too late - I can't identify which is the request for that response. So connection:willCacheResponse: is of no use to prevent caching.

I do not want to use connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse because otherwise I will have to reimplement the whole HTTP redirection logic myself.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thank you for your patience.